# How to Sort array as per another array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have array something like:

```
Array(
       [06:30 PM] => 2
       [03:00 AM] => 3
       [08:00 PM] => 4
     )
```

So I have used uksort to sort the key and array will be sorted like:

```
Array(
        [03:00 AM] => 3
        [06:30 PM] => 2
        [08:00 PM] => 4
 )
```

And code I have used is:

```
uksort($arr, function($a, $b) {
            return (strtotime(date('H:i',strtotime($a))) > strtotime(date('H:i',strtotime($b))));
        });
```

This array is have time in Key and count of value as value.Now, I have another array which contain the value of above keys.

```
Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Default
                    [1] => BHU
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Default
                    [1] => HOT
                    [2] => COLD
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Default
                    [1] => Test
                    [2] => Test1
                    [3] => Test2
                )
        )
```

Now, I want to sort this array also as per above array sorted. How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: this is not a good way i think  you want to first set values in key in place of count of values and than you want to sort it. Otherwise how you will sort values exactly as per time(which you consider as key)

Answer (score 1):

First, the code you wrote can be simplified as

```
uksort($arr, function($a, $b) {
    return ( strtotime($a) > strtotime($b) );
});
```

For the answer, It would be messy to make code for your array structure.

I would suggest making the following structure and then sorting with the code you wrote with little improvements i showed.

Check below,

```
Array
        (
            [06:30 PM] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Default
                    [1] => BHU
                )

            [03:00 AM] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Default
                    [1] => HOT
                    [2] => COLD
                )

            [08:00 PM] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Default
                    [1] => Test
                    [2] => Test1
                    [3] => Test2
                )
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$arr = array(
       '06:30 PM' => 2,
       '03:00 AM' => 3,
       '08:00 PM' => 4,
     );

$arr2 = array(
            '1' => array(
                    '0' => 'Default',
                    '1' => 'BHU'
                ),

            '2' => array(
                    '0' => 'Default',
                    '1' => 'HOT',
                    '2' => 'COLD',
                ),

            '3' => array(
                    '0' => 'Default',
                    '1' => 'Test',
                    '2' => 'Test1',
                    '3' => 'Test2',
                ),
        );

$arr3 = array_combine(array_keys($arr), $arr2);

uksort($arr3, function($a, $b) {
            return (strtotime(date('H:i',strtotime($a))) > strtotime(date('H:i',strtotime($b))));
        });

echo"<pre>";
print_r($arr3);   
?>
```

Here in this example first use array_keys in your first array it will take your keys as value and than combine it with your another array for it you will use array_combine in array_combine it will get first array value as key and second array value as value and than sort your array as per key
For more details you will refer this links:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php